# Unable to cast again int extracted from varbinary as varchar to int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am passing a parameter from stored procedure to my trigger on sql server

I am getting the true value on my trigger but am not able to convert back the int extracted as a varchar

I am getting the error below

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '50000...' to data type int.

```
declare @a varbinary(8);
select @a=CONVERT( varbinary(8),convert(varchar(8),50000))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @a;

declare @ParamPassedWhenSP_Called varchar(10);

select @ParamPassedWhenSP_Called=(SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), CONTEXT_INFO()))

select cast (@ParamPassedWhenSP_Called as int)
```

Comment: SQL tag is not meant to indicate RDMS SQL dialect, this SQL dialect code feels like SQL Server (MSSQL) or TSQL syntax.

Comment: yeah thanks i get it @RaymondNijland

Comment: `'50000...'` isn't an `int` though. It has several `.` characters at the end.

Comment: I know but its the result of converting back varbinary(8) to varchar(8) and the debugger is showing it 50000

Comment: Can you confirm the value of the variable `@ParamPassedWhenSP_Called` after calling the line of code: `select @ParamPassedWhenSP_Called=(SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), CONTEXT_INFO()))`.

Comment: @Angelo i added the picture above ,thank you

Comment: Please don't post pictures. If you want to supply sample data, do so as `text`.

Comment: I also can't replicate the problem. `SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(8),0x353030303030))` works fine.

Comment: @Larnu I deleted the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONVERT(varchar(8), CONTEXT_INFO())` is returning a value `50000` with remaining characters filled as `char(0)`.
You should try replacing char(0) with `''` before casting to int

```
select cast (REPLACE(@ParamPassedWhenSP_Called, CHAR(0), '') as int)
```